# Existence of the gcd

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a PID and $\sim$ be the equivalence relation $a\sim b :\Leftrightarrow\exists x\in R^{\times}:ax=b$. Consider $\bar{R}=R/\sim.$ Then I have shown that $[a]\leq [b]:\Leftrightarrow a|b$ is a partial order on $\bar{R}$.

> **claim.** For every $[a],[b]\in\bar{R}\setminus 0$ the set $\{[t]\in\bar{R}:t|a \text{ and }t|b\}$ has a maximal element. (A representative is called a gcd of $a$ and $b$.)

Well, I tried to use Zorn's lemma. Denote $P=\{[t]\in\bar{R}:t|a \text{ and }t|b\}$ is partial ordered by the partial order in $\bar{R}$. It is non empty since it includes the $[1]$. Now choose a totaly ordered subset $S\subset P$. Why does this have an upper bound in $P$? What can I choose?

Comment: a PID is a UFD. Proving this is quite technical. A UFD would make it more intuitive

Comment: I know this statement. How would you use this?

Comment: let $t_1...t_m=t | a=a_1 ... a_n$, in which they are all primes. then $t_1$ being prime implies $t_1|a_{i_1}$ for some $i_1$, can you continue?

Comment: Not really. You stillt want to use Zorn's lemma?

Comment: no, just technique. So $t_1| a_1$ (we can reorder the number), and since $a_1$ is prime then it's irreducible. So $t_1=a_1$.

Comment: Okay, but what does it help if we know $t_1=a_1$?

Comment: Then t2=a2,..... so all prime factor of t belong to prime factor of a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After showing that the relation is well defined, you can observe that
$$
[a]\le [b] \quad\text{if and only if}\quad (a)\supseteq (b)
$$
where $(x)$ denotes the principal ideal generated by $x\in R$.

Now, given $[a]$ and $[b]$, a candidate for being a maximal element is $(a)+(b)$. Set $(a)+(b)=(d)$ (which is possible because $R$ is a PID) and prove the claim.

$[d]\le[a]$ and $[d]\le[b]$

> It is clear that $(d)=(a)+(b)\supseteq (a)$ and $(d)=(a)+(b)\supseteq(b)$, so $[d]\le[a]$ and $[d]\le[b]$.

If $[c]\le[a]$ and $[c]\le[b]$, then $[c]\le[d]$

> If $[c]\le[a]$ and $[c]\le[b]$, we have $(c)\supseteq(a)$ and $(c)\supseteq(b)$, hence $(c)\supseteq(a)+(b)=(d)$. So $(d)$ is not only maximal, but actually a maximum.